# How To List All Articles for Menu » Articles » List All Categories type

Tags: articles, menu-item, menu, layout, article-manager

When creating a new *menu item type* that is **"Article » List All Categories"** – how can I display all of the actual articles for each sub-category?  As of right now, each sub-category being listed has a badge icon displaying a number to represent how many articles are within it's sub-category but I would like all of the actual articles for each sub-category to be displayed.

As a side note I have tried accomplishing this by using the *Menu Manager* to set the *Blog Layout » Include Subcategories* to **ALL** but that still is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, instead of using the *List All Categories* just choose a single article and then create a new module for that page to display all of your Category/Sub-Category articles. Here's how to do it...

1. Go to *Extensions » Module Manager* and Create a new *"Articles Category"* module, leave the mode set to "Normal"and specify the module position where you want this content to appear on your page.
2. Use the *"Menu Assignment"* tab to specify which page(s) you want to display this categories list on.
3. Next click the *"Filtering Options"* tab change the *"Category Filtering Type"* to *"Inclusive"* and select the categories you want to appear. You can also include any child categories.
4. Finally if you want to manipulate the category/article ordering you can click on the *"Ordering Options"* tabs.

Comment: What version of Joomla is this for? In JOomla 3, half these things are not present